# Overflow hidden not working in CSS grid images

Tags: html, css, overflow

I've been adding overflow hidden to the class "food_picture" and even the picture grid container class, but the images still expand when they are hovered on on top of other images. I just want them to transform within their fixed dimensions and not spill over into other images when hovered.

I also have an issue where if I set a background color behind the images or try to add an icon, it ruins the grid layout and also expands the images to their full height and width...

```
.picture_grid{
    max-width: 75vw;
    margin:2rem auto;
}

.food_title{
    max-width: 75vw;
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    padding: 3rem;
}

.food_title:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    background: #F4D06F;
    width: 15rem;
    height: 0.25rem;;
}


img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}



.food_picture:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    opacity: .5;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.food_picture{
    overflow: hidden;
}


.pic_1{
    grid-area: one;
}

.pic_2{
    grid-area: two;
}
.pic_3{
    grid-area: three;
}

.pic_4{
    grid-area: four;
}

.pic_5{
    grid-area: five;
}

.pic_6{
    grid-area: six;
}

.pic_7{
    grid-area: seven;
}

.pic_8{
    grid-area: eight;
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px){
    .picture_grid{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      grid-gap: 1rem;
    }
  }


@media screen and (min-width:768px) {

    .picture_grid {
        grid-template-columns: 300px 300px 300px 300px;
        grid-template-rows: 500px 500px 500px 500px;
        grid-template-areas: "six six six seven"
                            "eight eight four seven"
                            "three three three two"
                            "one one five two";
                            grid-row-gap: 1rem;
                            grid-column-gap: 1rem;
    }

}
```

```
<section class="our_work">
  <h2 class="food_title">Our Food</h2>
    <div class="picture_grid">
    <article class="food_picture pic_1">
      <img src="img/food_1.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="1">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_2">
      <img src="img/food_2.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="2">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_3">
      <img src="img/food_3.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="3">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_4">
      <img src="img/food_4.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="4">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_5">
      <img src="img/food_5.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="5">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_6">
      <img src="img/food_6.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="6">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_7">
      <img src="img/food_7.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="7">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_8">
      <img src="img/food_8.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="8">
      </a>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: transform:scale(x) should be applied to the children and overflow to the parent https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mNwRwm difference from your code : `.food_picture:hover` turned into `.food_picture:hover > *`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `width` and `height` properties for the `img` elements. Using `object-fit` and size properties is redundant, since cover will make the image fit its container.

```
img{
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Here's your updated example:

```css
.picture_grid{
    max-width: 75vw;
    margin:2rem auto;
}

.food_title{
    max-width: 75vw;
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    padding: 3rem;
}

.food_title:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    background: #F4D06F;
    width: 15rem;
    height: 0.25rem;;
}


img{
    object-fit: cover;
}



.food_picture:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    opacity: .5;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.food_picture{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.pic_1{
    grid-area: one;
}

.pic_2{
    grid-area: two;
}
.pic_3{
    grid-area: three;
}

.pic_4{
    grid-area: four;
}

.pic_5{
    grid-area: five;
}

.pic_6{
    grid-area: six;
}

.pic_7{
    grid-area: seven;
}

.pic_8{
    grid-area: eight;
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px){
    .picture_grid{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      grid-gap: 1rem;
    }
  }


@media screen and (min-width:768px) {

    .picture_grid {
        grid-template-columns: 300px 300px 300px 300px;
        grid-template-rows: 500px 500px 500px 500px;
        grid-template-areas: "six six six seven"
                            "eight eight four seven"
                            "three three three two"
                            "one one five two";
                            grid-row-gap: 1rem;
                            grid-column-gap: 1rem;
    }

}
```

```html
<section class="our_work">
  <h2 class="food_title">Our Food</h2>
    <div class="picture_grid">
    <article class="food_picture pic_1">
      <img src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="1">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_2">
      <img src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="2">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_3">
      <img src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="3">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_4">
      <img src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="4">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_5">
      <img src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="5">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_6">
      <img src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="6">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_7">
      <img src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="7">
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="food_picture pic_8">
      <img src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
      <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="8">
      </a>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: no it did not work and it affected my grids appearance now.

Comment: You set `overflow: hidden;` for your `.food_picture` class, but did not specify the element's size, so it will default to auto; Set the container size to a specific width and height (perhaps `width: 100%; height: 100%;`?) To allow the overflow to hide the oversized image.

Comment: I updated my example to set the specific size for the `.food_picture` container.

Comment: nothing changed on my end, I looked up that overflow: hidden needs a specified height for the element. Yet, I've added even a width and it still does not clip the extra part of the image. Even copy and pasted your code and it did not change as well.